# Recreating streetview effect in my own iPhone App

Tags: iphone, google-maps, quartz-graphics, google-street-view

My app allows you too "look" around a room in every similar manner to how you can "look" around a street when you are in streetview in the Maps application. Does anyone know of a simple way to recreate this effect?

I do have an image (like the streetview image) that I would like users to look around in.

Some ideas I have:

1) Put the image in a scroll view and let users pan and zoom. This doesn't seem like it would have the same effect as when you pan around the streetview, objects near the edges stretch to give you a "lens" type effect.

2) Apply a transform to the image before drawing it in a scroll view, and reapply the transform during scrolling. This transform would create the lens effect on the currently viewed part of the image.

3) Use open GL to create a hollow sphere and apply the image as a texture on the inside of the sphere.

1. doesn't seem like it would work
2. seems like my best option but I don't know what transform to use in quartz to create this effect. I like this though because it uses a scroll view and I don't have to recreate the panning, flicking and pinching code.
3. seems like overkill and too much work

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?